# How to add a character after every ODD line and before every EVEN line using Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a sample data like this:

```
line1 
line2 
line3 
line4 
line5
```

I want to add a dot after every ODD line to look like this:

```
line1 .
line2 
line3 .
line4 
line5 .
```

Then, I want to add a dot before the EVEN line to look like this:

```
line 1
. line 2
line 3
. line 4
line 5
```

Comment: Please, edit your question and add some sample input lines and expected result. And what have you tried? What is `something`? A constant, different for every lines? ...

Comment: I rewrote it for clarity, can you please take a look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(.+)(\R)(.+\R)?`
- Replace with: `$1 .$2. $3`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
(.+)        # group 1, 1 or more any character but newline
(\R)        # group 2, any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
(.+\R)?     # group 3, optional, 1 or more any character and a linebreak
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1 .$2. $3  # content of group 1, a space, a dot, content of group 2, a dot, a space, content of group 3
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]